# is it possible to perform two *ngFor directives on the same element?

Tags: angular

I have some elements nested within a `div`, and I have two services and each one brings data from different arrays.

I want one of the element to be created with the values on one of the arrays, and the second element with the values of the other one.

For a better understanding, this is the HTML templatecode:

```html
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let person of dataArray">
        <img height="200px" src={{image.src}} alt={{image.caption}}>
            <mat-grid-tile-footer>
            <h1>{{person.locationId.tutenUser.firstName}} </h1>
        </mat-grid-tile-footer>
    </mat-grid-tile>
```

I'd like the `img` to be created with the data in one array that I have (not showing here) and the `h1` to be created with the person variable, but since I'm already performing `*ngFor="let person of dataArray"` I don't how could I write another `*ngFor` to iterate over my images array.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: You should combine them in your component or service instead.

Comment: Combine both arrays in one and loop over it

Comment: but how can I do it? they are not local arrays, they come from a backend server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said the best way is to combine both arrays into one and loop over that one.

But if you really want to do it this way you can use the index if the order and length of the two arrays matches.

```html
     <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let person of dataArray; let i = index">
        <img height="200px" src={{imageArray[i].src}} alt={{imageArray[i].caption}}>
        <mat-grid-tile-footer>
            <h1>{{person.locationId.tutenUser.firstName}} </h1>
        </mat-grid-tile-footer>
    </mat-grid-tile>
```

So the person with index `0` has its corresponding image in `imageArray[0]`